# Location Based Ad system In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, google-maps, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

How to find which ad show to user using location(longitude and latitude)

DataBase structure

Ad Table

```
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`title` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`images` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`source_url` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`target` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`radius` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`distance` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`lat` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`lng` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`description` LONGTEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`deleted_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`disable_admin` ENUM('Y','N') NULL DEFAULT 'N' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
```

User Table

```
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`full_name` VARCHAR(500) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`email` VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`gender` ENUM('Male','Female') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Male' COLLATE
`birthday_date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`current_city` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`email_verif` ENUM('Y','N') NULL DEFAULT 'N' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`updated_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`current_lat` VARCHAR(500) NULL DEFAULT 'N' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`current_lng` VARCHAR(500) NULL DEFAULT 'N' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
```

When User login in system then ad will be show using user current_lat ,current_lng

Problem is if admin create a ad with 28524.9203 radius and 40.32 distance from current lng or lat then how to find which ad will be show to user

Please Help i am stack in

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might help: [Finding Points Within a Distance of a Latitude/Longitude Using Bounding Coordinates](http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates)

Particularly the section "3.1 Computing the Minimum and Maximum Latitude". Or this: [Selecting points within a bounding circle](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html)